# Hover event fires twice (on enter and leave) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hover

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
        });
    });
});
```

I applied this effect to my menu, so when the mouse goes over the link it shows this fade effect, but when the mouse is released from it, the effect plays again. It shouldnt. It should only play once when the mouse is over the link, not another time when the mouse is out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`.hover()` has two callbacks, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`.

You're probably better off with `mouseenter`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The jQuery `.hover()` event handles `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, not `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: @developius: `.mouseover()` is a shortcut for `.on('mouseover')`

Comment: @Blender it is, but it's not the recommended method because you can't do things like in diEcho's answer.

Comment: mouseenter is correct, per documentation: "when the mouse enters an element".

Answer (score 5):

try this with **jQuery v1.7**

```
$('#menu a').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.25});
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
    }
});
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/sA5C7/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try this. add $(this).stop() on hoverout event

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu a").hover(function () {
                $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.25 }, function () {
                    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
                });
            }, function () { $(this).stop(); });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#menu a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
        });
  }, 
  function () {
    //do nothing
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire once on hover, use mouseenter instead:

```
$("element").mouseenter(function(){
    //event here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check it you get the same object or not

example:

```
$('#updateCart').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
        if (event.handled !== true) { .....
                  //Put your code in here
          }
}
```